# js dropdown autoclose issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm using dropdown in react

```
const handleClickDropdown = (e) => {
    if (document.getElementById("dropdown-list")) {
        let dropdownList = document.getElementById("dropdown-list");
        dropdownList.style.display = dropdownList.style.display === "none" || dropdownList.style.display === "" ? "block" : "none";
    }
};
```

closing function

```
const handleDropdownClose = (event) => {
    if (event.target.className !== "dropdown-icon") {
        if (document.getElementById("dropdown-list")) {
            document.getElementById("dropdown-list").style.display = "none";
        }
};
```

listener func

```
window.onclick = function (event) {
        handleDropdownClose(event);
    }
};
```

my dropdown looks like

```
        <div className="dropdown">
            <label onClick={e => handleClickDropdown(e)}</label>
            <div id="dropdown-list" className="dropdown-content">
                <p1</p>
                <p>2</p>
                <p>3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
};
```

1 issue. For the first time there is no display: none, but display: "", so I have to use

```
   dropdownList.style.display = dropdownList.style.display === "none" || 
     dropdownList.style.display === "" ? "block" : "none";
```

2 issue. I have to click to show dropdown and to hide again and then again show to make click outside work. If I just click to show dropdown and then outside - it doesn't trigger. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `select` element for your drop-downs?
They work really well!

```
<select>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option>Option3</option>
    <option>Option4</option>
    <option>Option5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Veggieoskibroski it becomes more strange looking than before - an arrow appeared and the whole dropdown is not visible. Weird. https://ibb.co/9NWPFGp